# scanf in x86 assembly language

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86, nasm, scanf

I try to sort using x86 assembly language. I use `scanf` for taking in the values but I am not able to limit the number of elements to take. That is, my output is:

```
Enter the number of elements less than 10:
4
Enter the elements :
1
N value is 1
2
N value is 1
3
N value is 1
4
N value is 1
5
N value is 1
6
N value is 1
```

The problem is that it is not stopping after 4.

```
    extern printf
    extern scanf
    SECTION .data
    temp: dd 0
    n: dd 0
    i: dd 0
    j: dd 0
    k: dd 0
    l: dd 0

    ini: dd 10
    section .bss
       ;X      resw    1
       in1  resd    1
       in2  resd    1       

    SECTION .text
    global main
main:
    push ecx
    push dword fmt0
    call printf
    add esp, 4
    pop ecx
    push edx

    push in1
    push dword fmt1
    call scanf
    add esp, 8
    pop edx
    mov eax,[in1]
    mov [n],eax

    ;push ecx
    ;push dword [n]
    ;push dword fmt6
    ;call printf
    ;add esp, 8
    ;pop ecx

    push ecx
    push dword fmt2
    call printf
    add esp, 4
    pop ecx
    jmp L$2

L$1:
    mov  eax,[j]
    mov  ebx,1
    mov ecx,eax
    add ecx,ebx
    push edx
    push dword ecx
    push dword fmt6
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    pop edx 

L$2:
    mov  eax,ecx
    mov  ebx,[n]
    cmp eax , ebx
    jg L$3      
    push eax
        push edx
    push in2
    push dword fmt3
    call scanf
    add esp, 8
    pop edx
    pop eax
    mov ecx,[in2]
    mov [ini],ecx
    jmp L$1

L$3:
    jmp L$5

L$4:
    mov  eax,[k]
    mov  ebx,1
    mov ecx,eax
    add ecx,ebx

L$5:
    mov  eax,[i]
    mov  ebx,[n]
    cmp eax , ebx
    jl L$6
    jmp L$8

L$7:
    mov  eax,1
    mov ebx,eax
    add ebx,eax
    mov  ecx,[i]
    mov edi,ecx
    add edi,ebx

L$8:
    mov  eax,[j]
    mov  ebx,[n]
    cmp eax , ebx
    jl L$9
    mov  edi,ini
    mov  esi,[k]
    mov ecx ,[edi + 4*esi]

    mov  ebx,[i]
    mov eax ,[edi + 4*ebx]
    cmp ecx , eax
    mov eax ,[edi + 4*ebx]
    mov [temp], eax
    mov ecx ,[edi + 4*esi]
    mov [ini + 4*ebx], ecx
    mov [ini + 4*esi], eax

L$11:
    jmp L$7
L$9:
    jmp L$4

L$6:
    push ecx
    push dword fmt4
    call printf
    add esp, 4
    pop ecx
    jmp L$13

L$12:
    mov  eax,[l]
    mov  ebx,1
    mov ecx,eax
    add ecx,ebx

L$13:
    mov  eax,[l]
    mov  ebx,[n]
    cmp eax , ebx
    jl L$14

    push ecx
    push dword [ini]
    push dword fmt5
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    pop ecx
    jmp L$12

L$14:
    ret

fmt0:   db "Enter the number of elements lessthan 10:",10,0
fmt1:   db "%d",0
fmt2:   db "Enter the elements :",10,0
fmt3:   db "%d",0
fmt4:   db "The sorted Array is :",10,0
fmt5:   db "%d",10,0
fmt6:    db "N value is %d",10,0
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your intention was to use `[j]` to hold the number of values that you've input, and increment it each time through the loop. You load the value at `L$1`, add one to it and save in the CX register, but you never store the modified value anywhere in memory. So the next time through the loop, `[j]` is still 0.

You need to store that value after you've incremented:

```
add ecx,ebx
mov [j], ecx  ; Store the incremented value
```

Hint: Some comments in your code would be useful. Perhaps one line at each major label that says what you're doing? You'll be happy those are there when you come back to look at your code next month.